# Hidden html inputs versus using a pathVariable in the URL of a PUT HTTP request

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, put

My application currently **makes massive use of hidden inputs** such as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="123456"/>
```

For instance, using the above hidden input **I can keep the id/pk of my object without displaying it to the end user**.

I feel this **goes against the principles of REST** and I would like to know whether using a **PUT url** such as:

`/advertisement/childminder/123456/edit`

and doing away with the hidden input altogether **might not be a better idea**...

Can anyone please advise?

**edit**: *I have edited my question and changed from POST to PUT because I am dealing with modification and not creation.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an "edit" as part of the URL smells of RPC-over-HTTP style programming. And tunneling edits through POST is also considered an [REST anti-pattern](http://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-anti-patterns).

REST is about putting the verbs in the HTTP method *and* [using hypertext](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven). Stefan Tilkov had an old but [helpful introduction to REST](http://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-introduction) that addresses your question.

Short: [Wikipedia: REST - RESTful web APIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#RESTful_web_APIs) (especially the usage of POST: Don't use it for edits on none-collections - use it for creation)!

Comment: Hi! I have edited my post to take into account the fact that modifications are dealt with PUTs and not POSTs. The interrogation about hidden inputs vs IDs in URLs remains...

Comment: Good. But the URL would be PUT "/advertisement/childminder/123456" (without "/edit"). "edit" is a verb that is already expressed through your PUT.

Comment: I see... Then you advise putting the IDs in the PUT url e.g. `/advertisement/childminder/123456̀` as opposed to using hidden inputs?

Comment: Yes. Your "Resource" needs something to identify it - and that identifier is (some part of) the URI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#Guiding_principles_of_the_interface

Comment: Umm... My question was also related to PUT urls vs hidden inputs. You see? I was expecting a kind of PROS and CONS reply...

Comment: Well, if you are talking "RESTful" and "create", then the one big PRO is "REST requires that the URI" identifies the resource. If you are talking about non-REST APIs, PROs and CONS might make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the purpose of restful url is to create a simple looking url and also consistent pattern making it easy for developers to learn how to use your APIs.

if you are hiding insensitive or trivial information there is no harm in using hidden tag.

A piece of Advice is either use /advertisement/childminder/123456/edit or use hidden style,but don't mix both styles in one application.

**Use hidden fields to pass along information to the forms that is generated by the program, script, or web page, or that the form user might not know, such as the exact time the form was loaded.
`Remember that hidden fields are not hidden from view`. Your readers can see them if they view the source of your web page. So you should never use a hidden input field to store passwords or any other sensitive information.**

Comment: Thanks for your input. Please note that my question really is about **POST HTTP requests**. You don't seem to take this into account in your answer...

Comment: @balteo I know that.You think the behavior should change for POST request?What are you expecting.?

Comment: @balteo I think you wana open the edit page of a user via its primary key and that is why you are hiding it.Well in this case it is not a good idea to store primary key of a user in this way.You can use session variable to store the user details and the later user session variable to fetch the details from the controller .Please note that such techniques are prone to attacks and would recommend you to go through OWASP and CSRF.

Comment: I was rather looking for authoritative advice from people with experience in REST. Furthermore, my question does not really relate to security but more to REST standards...